# How to have Express.js server file using router path as root?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a directory structure like this

```
root
  private
    js
    css
    index.html
  app.js
  privateRouter.js
  ...
```

In my index.html I reference the js and css files using relative path like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

On the server side I have a private router checks for authentication before serving these files:

In app.js:

```js
app.use("/private", privateRouter);
```

in privateRouter.js:

```js
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    isAuthenticated(req) ? next() : res.redirect("/");
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(require('path').join(__dirname + "/private/index.html"));
});
```

So now if I visit `http://mywebsite.com/private` I will get the the index.html, but the request of js/css files from the browser comes back to the server as `http://mywebsite.com/js` instead of `http://mywebsite.com/private/js`, thus returns file not found.

Alternatively if I serve files statically, the browser knows to request from `/private/js`:

```js
app.use("/private", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private')));
```

But I can't server statically because I need to authenticate specific files and not serve all files publicly. And I don't want to have to append `private/` before all file references on client side. I don't understand why when serving statically the server knows to use `/private` as root but when using a router it uses `/` as root.

**How can I keep the url as `http://mywebsite.com/private` while not having to append `private/` in all file references on the client side?**

I'm new to express.js and it was also difficult for me to formulate the question. I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something about express.js works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a request's URL using middleware for internal routing:

```js
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
  req.url = "/private" + req.url; // prepend "/private" to the url
  next();
});
```

---

You can also set the base URL using the [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag, which means you only need to specify the base URL once per page.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="private">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This should then send the requests to:

- /private/css/index.css
- /private/js/index.js

However, you will still need code to handle these paths, otherwise, you will still get the 404 not found error.

Comment: thanks for the repsonse! I'm looking for a more generic solution as this still requires me to edit every html and js file that make relative references. If I decide to rename/move the private directory in the future then every file that made a reference would need to be modified.

Comment: I updated my answer to fit your requirements a little bit better. You may have to add some logic to it, but it should work.

Comment: it didn't work, the js and css files still points to / rather than /private. The private router also ends up going to /private rather than /

Comment: As I said, you would need to add some logic, like `if(req.path === "/"){next();}`. Also, don't put the code in the router, but on the main app. (in app.js, not privateRouter.js)